# Get Http Request Body from cxf message

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, interceptor

I am trying to write a cxf interceptor which will forward all the incoming requests from my app to another app. However for POST requests I am unable to get the body of the request.

The code I am using looks like :

```
String body = message.getContent(String.class);
```

However the body comes as null. I looked into cxf code & it looks like you have to specify the exact class (Ex : ArrayList) to get the body. My app has multiple such message classes. I wanted to know if there is a method by which I can avoid writing multiple checks for each of my POJO class & do it in a single `if`.

Comment: Do message.getContent(InputStream.class), use CXF 
IOUtils to read into String. Refer http://www.javatips.net/blog/cxf-interceptor-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call message.getContent(InputStream.class) and use CXF IOUtils to read into String. Please refer [javatips.net/blog/cxf-interceptor-example](http://javatips.net/blog/cxf-interceptor-example) for more details

Comment: The most important piece of code is Phase.RECEIVE, as it makes sure that the body is present in the InputStream

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
XMLStreamReader body  = message.getContent(XMLStreamReader.class);
```